# Aggregating column informations in Databricks df without using UDF

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe df looks like this:

| customer | commodity | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | GAS | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| A | POWER | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| B | GAS | 01/02/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| B | POWER | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| C | GAS | 01/03/2023 | 19/12/2023 |
| C | POWER | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| D | POWER | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |

I need to create for each customer an aggregate column "**commodity_aggr**".

Using these conditions:

**Condition 1**:
If only one row exists for a customer code and it has a distinct count of commodities = 1, it's labeled as MONO.

- start_date: Minimum start date.
- end_date: Minimum end date.

**Condition 2**:
If only one row exists for a customer code and it has a distinct count of commodities > 1, it's labeled as DUAL.

- start_date: Minimum start date.
- end_date: Minimum end date.

**Condition 3**:
If two rows exist for a customer code, it has a distinct count of commodities > 1, and the start date of the first is before or equal to the start date of the second, the first row is MONO, and the second is DUAL.

- MONO start_date: Minimum start date of the first row.
- MONO end date: Minimum start date of the second row.
- DUAL start_date: Minimum start date of the second row.
- DUAL end date: Maximum end date of the second row.

**Condition 4**:
If two rows exist for a customer code, it has a distinct count of commodities > 1, and the end date of the first is before or equal to the end date of the second, the first row is DUAL, and the second is MONO.

- DUAL start_date: Minimum start date of the second row.
- DUAL end date: Maximum end date of the second row.
- MONO start_date: Minimum start date of the first row.
- MONO end date: Minimum start date of the second row.

Eventually, the data should look like this:

| customer | commodity_aggr | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | MONO | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| B | MONO | 01/02/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| B | DUAL | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| C | DUAL | 01/03/2023 | 19/12/2023 |
| C | MONO | 19/12/2023 | 19/02/2024 |
| D | MONO | 01/03/2023 | 19/02/2024 |

I am working in Databricks, so both SQL and pyspark are fine
My cluster in Unity Catalog Databricks have Runtime 13.1 so UDF functions are not supported.

Any help or comments are highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Given the structure of your input, how can you have a customer with only one row but two commodities to their name?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You're absolutely right. I've revised the conditions and corrected the post.